# Unable to connect Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger, studio3t

I have installed mongodb ans Studio 3T on windows 10, 64 bit system but when I run

```
mongod --auth --dbpath C:\data\db --storageEngine wiredTiger
```

this command, it says 'mongod' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I am not sure why this error comes even mongo.exe and mongod.exe is available under "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin" folder

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because you need to cd into the directory where the mongodb folders are created when you installed it.

For windows:- C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\ as per [click here](https://docs.mongodb.com/tutorials/install-mongodb-on-windows/)

Details Steps for you:-

1. cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin
2. check for mongo.exe, mongod.exe and etc.
3. mongod.exe --auth --dbpath C:\data\db --storageEngine wiredTiger
4. you should be able to connect now.

Note:- Above steps assumes that Mongodb service is running. If not [Click here](https://docs.mongodb.com/tutorials/install-mongodb-on-windows/)

OR you can add the path C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin to enviornment variable.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, just added "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin" path to environmental variable.